# Migrate from Tomcat to WAS

Tags: java, tomcat, websphere

A few weeks ago I [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728942/converting-war-to-ear-and-other-glassfish-stories) about Application Servers. It happens that my bosses are moving to WAS and my web application needs to move along. Problem is I have little idea of application servers.

In my application I used web.xml and tomcat-users.xml to define roles and users. I have to do this in the WAS server, so what do I need to do? I mean, I have read that it defines some security roles in the application.xml that binds with the WAS server, and that they need some ids that look through the ibm-application-bnd.xmi

It also seems that I need some kind of ibm-web-bnd.xmi to just reconfigure my web.xml with the same users (which gets me terribly confused).

Do I need to create these files (I don't have a RAS, just an Eclipse Galileo (yeah, I also sometime think I am playing in hard mode), so I have no way to do this automatically) or can I just configure the application.xml and the web.xml correctly without these files? I have managed myself to more or less create these files and finally create an EAR that the WAS has deployed (correctly, it says).

This sounds a hell of lot complex for just a user validation, so I don't now if I am right or wrong. 
Probably wrong, since WAS keeps saying "com.ibm.websphere.security.PasswordCheckFailedException: No user wasadmin found".

Is there any insightful documentation of how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WAS has a webbased admin console wherein you configure this kind of things with a few mouseclicks. If I recall correctly, it's listening on HTTP port 9090 or so, but this is configureable as well. I suggest you to read [this RedBook](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247615.html) to learn how to use the WAS admin console.

Leave the `tomcat-users.xml` out of the scope. However keep the `security-constraint` and `login-config` in the `web.xml`.

Comment: Thanks for the red book! It's really insgihtful :)
Thanks for the help, I could finally login with "AllAuthenticatedUsers" with out any xmi file. I suposse I can login with any user now. Although I keep trying. This WAS server is a very complicated software compared to my little tomcat...